# How to combine equation and cases

Tags: equations

I'm trying to type a piecewise function and enumerate it. I'm aware that `equation` would do the enumeration by putting a number behind the equation. However, if I use the following code, the number would appear in front of the function.

How could I amend it to make the number appear behind the function?

```
\begin{equation}
    f(c|\theta)=
     \begin{cases}
        \frac{n!}{c_1!,...,c_6!}\theta_1^{c_1}\times\cdot\cdot\cdot\times\theta_6^{c_6},&\text{when $n=c_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+c_6$} \\
        0,&\text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Update:

```
\documentclass[a4papper 12pt]{amsart}

\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.25cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, final]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Welcome ro TeX SX! Are you using the `leqno` option instead of the default `reqno`?

Comment: I'm using an overleaf template and I'm not familiar with the code to set this option so I'm not sure what the option is. If the option is `leqno`, how should I change it to `reqno`? @Bernard

Comment: Usuallu it is set as an option of `\documentclass` or of `\usepackage{amsmath}` Do your other numbered equations have their number on the left side?

Comment: Yes. I tried another one and the number is also on the left side. I have updated the question with the code before `\begin{document}`. Both `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` look normal. @Bernard

Comment: Try adding `[reqno]` as an option to amsmath. Unless you're satisfied in general with the equation number on the left, and want to change it only for some specific cases?

Comment: This led to an error message and it suggested me to add `leqno,centertags,,reqno` as an option to `\documentclass` and this worked fine... Do you have any ideas for the reason of this? @Bernard

Comment: Probably amsart already loads  amsmath (so you shouldn't load it), with option `leqno`, so you have conflicying options. If you load `reqno` with the document class, it takes it  into account and passes it to amsmath.

Comment: `amsart` by default puts equation numbers on the left.  (Reason: so they don't conflict with the tombstone when a proof ends with an equation.)  So if you want *all* equation numbers on the right, enter the option `[reqno]` with the document class.  (This is a case where knowing the document class is *essential*.)